# TestNG is not running tests

Tags: java, testing, testng

I've set up TestNG and am trying to run it, but it's not running any of my classes. Here's the output:

```
[SuiteRunner] Created 1 TestRunners
[TestRunner] Running test GRP-test on 0  classes,  included groups:[test ] exclu
ded groups:[]
===== Invoked methods
=====
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\Test by groups\GRP-test.ht
ml
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\Test by groups\GRP-test.xm
l

===============================================
    GRP-test
    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Test by groups
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\testng-results.xml
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@4e27c652: 12 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 1 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter@201075c5: 3 ms
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\index.html
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@bb2d83d: 29 ms
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\old\Test by groups\toc.htm
l
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\old\Test by groups\GRP-tes
t.properties
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\old\Test by groups\index.h
tml
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\old\Test by groups\main.ht
ml
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\old\Test by groups\groups.
html
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\old\Test by groups\methods
.html
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\old\Test by groups\methods
.html
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\old\Test by groups\methods
-alphabetical.html
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\old\Test by groups\methods
-alphabetical.html
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\old\Test by groups\classes
.html
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\old\Test by groups\reporte
r-output.html
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\old\Test by groups\methods
-not-run.html
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\old\Test by groups\testng.
xml.html
Creating C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\test-output\old\index.html
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@3c8fa832: 27 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@4045acb5: 0 ms
```

and here's my xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Test by groups">
      <test verbose="10" name="GRP-test">
       <groups>
        <run>
          <include name="test"/>
        </run>
       </groups>

      </test> <!-- GRP-test -->
    </suite> <!-- Test by groups -->
```

What I'm trying to do is get my selenium tests to run. I've gotten them to run successfully in eclipse, but I'm moving over to the command line to make it a bit easier (irony, right?).

Here's my command line:

```
C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test>java -cp C:\Users\myName\Documents\Eclipse\li
bs\testng-6.8.jar;C:\Users\myName\workspace\Test\bin\test\* org.testng.TestNG
testng.xml
```

Comment: Do you have any `@Test` methods? Are you importing testng's Test (and not junit's)?

Comment: Are your methods in the "test" group?

Comment: I have 2 @Test methods I'm using in the "test" group. When I use that xml in eclipse it all works, but form the command line it does as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add classes or package from which the groups would be picked up.  Just the groups tag won't work.

Adding an example from testng [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methods) (you can specify a package as well based on need):

```
<test name="Test1">
  <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="functest"/>
    </run>
  </groups>
  <classes>
    <class name="example1.Test1"/>
  </classes>
</test>
```

Comment: But why would that xml work when in Eclipse but not from the command line?

Comment: How do u trigger your cases in eclipse?

Comment: I'm using the testNG plugin, you just go to Project>Run Configuration

Comment: Ok and what do you specify as your config?  If you want to simulate running only based on your XML, then jus right click on your XML and select run as Testng suite.  If that runs, then I can check it up further.